# Continuing a failed print when you have Auto Mesh Bed Leveling

Tags: diy-3d-printer

When you have Auto Mesh Bed Leveling enabled on your printer, it's not possible to continue a failed print, is it?

Answer (score 4):

Continuing a failed print has nothing to do with automatic bed leveling. It has everything to do with knowing which line failed, repositioning to resume from that point, and resuming from that line of code.

Comment: but you won't be able to do a g29 because your half printed part will be in the way. Will it not be slightly off the z axis?

Comment: You may be able to G29 the surface of the print; my printers don't do G29; we set the Z manually. I would make a copy of the file, strip out the moves already executed, insert a G92 Z## where ## is the present Z position, and restart the print from there, with this edited file.

Comment: I'm not sure this answer is right. The printer will no longer compensate in the same way, so if your bed was really tilted, the newly printed layers won't be in the same plane as the original layers.

Comment: @Ageis The compensation of the shape of the bed when using ABL is only active for a few mm's of your print if it has `#define ENABLE_LEVELING_FADE_HEIGHT` enabled. The height can be set with `M420 Z<height>`

Answer (score 1):

So like resuming any print, if you've already done the work to find the layer you failed at, edited the G-code to start from that layer. But now you feel stuck because to start a print you need to home your printer right? And homing with a BLTouch makes it probe the center of your bed... which happens to be where your print is at. IF you're on Klipper, you can put something like this here:

```
[homing_override]
set_position_z:0
gcode:
 G90
 G1 Z10 F600
 G28 X Y
 #G1 X161 Y125 F6000 ;old bed center
 G1 X245 Y215 F6000 ;far right corner of the bed. You may have to adjust your X and Y for your BLTouch location as mine is on a Hero Me hotend
 G28 Z
 G1 Z100 F24000 ; move Z-axis up so hotend doesn't hit the print when zeroing. Adjust this as needed to clear your print from where it failed
 G1 X0 Y0 F24000
```

And from there, the printer should Home and you can start your partial G-code from here. IF YOU HAVE KLIPPER. Make sure to remove any purge lines or stuff like that from your Start Print code.